# Elasticsearch / Lucene Acronym Search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I find that acronyms in company names come in a variety of formats e.g.

`AB Industries
A.B. Industries
A B Industries`

These names might be in my indexed data in any of these formats, and might come in a search query in any of these formats too.

Is there any combination of filters and tokenizers that can enable a search for any of the listed formats to find the indexed doc in any of the listed formats?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using StandardAnalyzer your data will be delimited by '.' and A and B will be indexed as separate terms.

I would suggest experimenting with below options

1) Implement your own custom analyzer, remove StandardFilter and use ClassicTokenizer with LowerCaseFilter. (according to ClassicTokenizer doc - "Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuation. However, a dot that's not followed by whitespace is considered part of a token"

2) If above works, still "A.B" will be indexed as "A.B" thus query "AB" will not find any match. To fix this completely, you have to have your tokenizer where you can normalize tokens A.B->AB, A B-> AB and so on before indexing.

You can get tons of examples of custom tokenizers and analyzers on google.

Let me know experiment status.